# Exporting a function declared as constant in ES6

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, eslint

I followed a guide to implement **REDUX** in my `react-native` app. I am trying to implement **actions** but my `eslint`keeps on giving this error on 8th line-

```
[eslint] Prefer default export. (import/prefer-default-export)
```

My code is -

```
import * as types from './types';

const incrementCounter = counterValue => ({
  type: types.INCREMENT_COUNTER,
  counterValue,
});

export { incrementCounter };
```

My question is what is the proper way to export this constant function in ES6 ?

Comment: Your syntax is fine. ESLint is triggering because according to your rule, if your module *only has one export* then it should be the *default*. According to that rule, you should only `export { ... }` if you have more than one. To stick to your rules: `export default incrementCounter`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest change would be to add `as default` to your  `export { incrementCounter };`. However, to export your function as the default export you'd rather write

```
import * as types from './types';

export default counterValue => ({
  type: types.INCREMENT_COUNTER,
  counterValue,
});
```

or

```
import * as types from './types';

export default function incrementCounter(counterValue) {
  return {
    type: types.INCREMENT_COUNTER,
    counterValue,
  };
}
```

Comment: The first one is also giving an error `[eslint]Parsing error: Unexpected token` at `const`.

Comment: @KaranHudia You're right, that should be `export default counterValue => ...` without the `const`.

Answer (score 1):

In config.js

```
// Declaration of const 

const config = {
    name: 'test'
};

export default config
```

In another file

```
// Using const 

import * as config from '../config';

let name = config.name;
```

Comment: Well `module.exports` is not really an ES6 way.

Answer (score 1):

`import/prefer-default-export` is a questionable rule, 
using **`default exports`** you will lose *type consistence* and your *IDE* won't be longer able to help you with refactoring, inspection and code completion.

you will be always able to import with a different name using *import aliases*: `import {incrementCounter as foo} from 'incrementCounter'`

It may appear as a personal opinion, but, I strongly suggest you to keep `named exports` and edit your `.eslintrc`:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "import/prefer-default-export" : 0
  }
}
```

Please, refer to this discussion:
https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1365

Comment: Can you explain that first paragraph? Why would that be any different than named exports when it comes to an IDE?

Comment: Because the reference isn't explicit, please follow the discussion on github.

Comment: I read the discussion. I also read the author's thoughts and agree that the refactoring is in the *file*. Kind of like saying avoid `import as` because it can't be refactored. Each has it's own edge cases, but the default export rule just edges towards keeping the file minimal to avoid that refactoring. Anyway, IMO :)

Comment: Refactoring belongs to the `type`, if you use `default exports`, then, it will left to the file only and you will lose some feature. If you don't want to bound imports, then, you can use aliases.